# Love movie where a guy cheats on the female protagonist

Tags: identify-this-movie, romance

There was this movie I watched a year ago and obviously forgotten the name of it.

The necessary points of information are:

- It was in colour
- It was set in the USA
- The characters had american accents so it was also filmed there.
- I am not sure when it was showing, I saw it a year ago.

### What I remember from the plot though some scenes and descriptions may not match the movie requested (and in no particular order):

- The protagonst was a female young adult.
- The woman had an affair with her boyfriend and they broke up.
- She met some guy on a beach who was fairly muscular and she started flirting with him.
- I do know that the muscular man and the woman decided to go on a little night dare trip (the guy was immature and very)
- They turned up at a fast food place and they (went through the drive through) decided it would be funny to do a little prank.
- So the guy spoke through the com (this wont be exactly what he said):

  > Can we have some burgers and...(makes the noise of static with mouth) some drink...(static) and some...(static) fries with that...(static)
- The guy at the window said:

  > Ok but why is the com doing that?
- Then the guy in the car with the woman said back through:

  > I don't... (static) ...ow (was meant to say 'know')
- This kept up for a little bit with the false static, then the guy at the window got annoyed and yelled through the window:

  > Come up to the Window!
- So they drove up to the window and got their driks and stuff, the guy in the car said that they need to fix their com, the window guy said he thought so too, and he starts talking to them in a friendly but weird way.
- When the window guy had finished talking, the guy in the car said something I can't remember (it was meant to be an insult), the guy in the window got upset and started saying that is not nice.
- When the guy in the car was starting to call him the insult, the window guy go quite upset and then as he went to drive off, he called the guy that again.
- The window guy then said to the other staff:

  > Group hug, group hug
- The other staff gave him the group hug as intended.

### Another scene:

- The protagonist and the other muscular guy went on a little night exercise about something the guy heard was happening(I think it was the same night as the fast food prank, I could be wrong) and the muscular guy gave the woman a walkie talkie, the woman not sure why. He gave a call sign to both of them, can't remember what they were.
- They decided to have a bit of fun and they ran down the hillside, the guy got a little over exagerated and with mock worry and panic and started saying into the radio:

  > (woman's call sign), where are you, where are you?
- She responded saying:

  > I'm right here, I'm right here.
- I can't exactly what they did in that two minutes, but I do remember that there was a car on the road bumping around and the two of them went up to the car cautiously (the guy had a torch) and crouched next to the car.
- The guy then shone the torch into the car's tinted windows, the window rolled down and there is the same guy he was insulting at the fast food store having anal sex with another guy.
- When the two saw eah toher, they screamed into each other's faces.
- The woman and guy took off running.

### Another scene:

- I remember that the man immature guy said to the woman that she needed to be at his room at 6:00pm sharp, she was on the road trying to get there at near 6:00.
- The guy then started making his room look nice and rehearsed some ways that he could engage her to do sexual activites with him.
- When he looked at his watch, it was past 6:00 and he was getting impatient.
- The woman was also getting worried she wouldn't arrive on time.
- When the guy gave up waiting, he went to the bar on the next floor and started chatting some other girl up, meanwhile, his actual date was on her way (still)
- When the protagonist made it to the hotel (it was a hotel by the way guys) she went to check in at the reception, at this VERY moment, her date walks past with another girl holding his hand, the two (both apparent dates) didn't see each other.
- After this, the protagonist went into the allocated room he was in, the door to the bedroom was closed and she was standing in the main room.
- She stared at the door and starting stripping down, while saying:

  > And I'm about to see the man of my dreams.
- She stripped right donw to the bra and underwear (she was wearing G-strings) and approached the door.
- She opened the door to about a 45 degree angle and there he was, laying naked on the bed with some naked woman sitting on him jumping up and down (obviously having sex).
- The protagonist saw him and her mouth gaped open.
- The guy ALSO saw her and he said:

  > (protagonist's name), you're here.
- Right as he finished that sentenced the girl was bucking extravagantly and the guy's head was rolling around, his eyes half closed and he looked like he was having the most amount of pleasure he could have.
- The protagonist ran out of the room, grabbed her clothes and ran out of the main room, the receptionist (another guy) saw her almost naked and he said:

  > I love my job (as a gasp)

Then said

> Who's your daddy, who's your daddy, who's your daddy?

- He was saying this while hitting the service bell and then he did a wolf call multiple times, then he stuck his tongue out like a dog and was panting.
- The protagonist payed no attention to it.
- The protagonist was driving back home (no clue if she got dressed) and while driving, she was crying and then she crashed.
- She woke in hospital, I have no idea what happened in the hospital.

### Other remembered scenes:

- After this happened. The Protagonist went to see her ex and he told her:

  > I told you this was going to happen
- After saying this, he hugged her and they got back together again (I think)

I can't remember what happened after this.

Thanks guys, your help is much appreciated as I would like to watch this movie again. I was as descriptive as possible from what I remembered as to avoid confusion. Thanks again.

Comment: Did they imitate the drive-thru scene from Wayne's World? See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXQhdB1y674

Comment: Holy crap, this is one of the most detailed ID questions I've ever seen here!

Comment: @Anne Daunted Um,I think she was brown haired, she was caucasian as well

Comment: I also mentioned that I was sure the movie was made in the USA due to the accent, I don't know when it took place either...I mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Ah yes, one thing did suddenly come back to me... The protagonist's name was **Meg** and that happens to be the only name I remember :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [Totally Blonde](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0200954/combined) from 2001 with Krista Allen and Michael Buble. [From Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_Blonde):

> Meg Peters just can't seem to find Mr. Right, until one day she bleaches her hair blonde. Men begin to swarm around, but none she feels is Mr. Right until she meets a crooner at a local club (Michael Buble). The plot thickens when she also meets an old high-school friend, now a wealthy but muscle-bound hunk (Brody Hutzler).

Everything you mentioned is there. For instance, the buff guy (Hutzler) is very immature and pranks the gay drive thru guy whose co-workers then comfort him with a group hug, and you can glimpse his late night covert mission with her (where he calls for her on a walkie talkie and she tells him she's right next to him) in the trailer below around 0:55. (And the randy hotel clerks appear [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1g5OE4YW5s).) This comedy was poorly received, with most of the praise going to Buble's singing. The trailer:

Comment: wow, released same year as Legally Blonde... coincidence?

Comment: @ShizZ. Let me get this straight, are you accusing the director of such classics as *Pop Star Puppy* of Asylum-like shenanigans? ;)